# Using DbContext dynamically

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I have a multiple DBs with with identical schema.
In my code, I would like to query one of the DBs by a parameter, which change dynamically.

Now it looks something like this:

```
public void saveNewUser(User user, string type)
{
        if (type == "A")
        {
            using (var db = new AEntities())
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            using (var db = new BEntities())
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

 }
```

Instead, I would like to do something like this:

```
public void saveNewUser(User user, string type)
{
        using (var db = new GeneralEntity(type))
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: Are the two entities different object types?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I was looking for is how to return the AEntity / BEntity dynamically, the objects already exists.

What I have done is this:

```
public class DbContextGeneral : DbContext
{
    public virtual Users;
}

public class AEntity : DbContextGeneral
{
    public override Users;
}
public class BEntity : DbContextGeneral
{
    public override Users;
}
```

In order to receive the type dynamically:

```
private DbContextGeneral GetDBInstance(string value)
{
    if (value == "A")
    {
        return new AEntity();
    }
    return new BEntity();
}
```

And then, finally:

```
using (var db = GetDBInstance(value))
{
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I have only one DbContext to solve similar problems. I just modify the connection string at runtime. Entity Framework supports this by allowing you to call the constructor with a connection string.

I allow administrators to maintain settings as profiles, for a given model,  that the application stores as a collection of encrypted SQL settings. At runtime, this list is loaded as dictionary with the profile name ("A", "B") serving as keys.

Then use the DbContext constructor that expects a connection string and pass it a built connection string based on your target db:

```
// the model name in the app.config connection string (any model name - Model1?)
private string BuildConnectionString(string profile)
{
    // configuration would hold the collection of settings - however you prefer to provide this
    var settings = configuration.GetConnectionSettings(profile);
    // Build the provider connection string with configurable settings
    var providerSB = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        InitialCatalog = settings.InitialCatalog,
        DataSource = settings.DataSource,
        UserID = settings.User,
        Password = settings.Password
    };    
    var efConnection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    // or the config file based connection without provider connection string
    // var efConnection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(@"metadata=res://*/model1.csdl|res://*/model1.ssdl|res://*/model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;");
    efConnection.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    efConnection.ProviderConnectionString = providerSB.ConnectionString;
    // based on whether you choose to supply the app.config connection string to the constructor
    efConnection.Metadata = "res://*/Model.DbEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.DbEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.DbEntities.msl", model;
    return efConnection.ToString();

}
```

Then in your example, you will only use one DbContext:

```
using (var db = new DbEntities(BuildConnectionString("A")))
{
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like a factory class maybe?

```
public void saveNewUser(User user, string type)
{
        using (var db = myclass.GetGeneralEntity(type))
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Comment: What would the GetGeneralEntity will return?

Comment: `GetGeneralEntity` would be your method to return the correct entity model. This is where your `switch` would be.

Answer (score 0):

[DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) has method [Set<TEntity>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) which returns a generic [DbSet<TEntity>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx). You can use this instead of the added properties to any override of a `DbContext`, ie. reference the base class `DbContext` in your calling code and it will not care what the actual instance is for that `DbContext`.

```
public class MyClass  {
    private DbContext _context;
    public MyClass(DbContext context){
        _context = context;
    }

    public void saveNewUser(User user)
    {
        _context.Set<User>.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The example above relies on [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to get the correct `DbContext` instance in the constructor, it does not care which specific implementation as long as it knows about the entity `User` later on when the method `saveNewUser` is called (otherwise exception will be thrown). The DI framework can also handle disposing the created `DbContext` or you can implement `IDisposable` to `MyClass` and dispose of `DbContext` in the disposing method. Alternatively you can inject a `DbContext` factory to create one when needed. (*there are many options, just depends on your preferred framework and probably how your app is currently structured*).

### Assumption

I assumed that you meant that the actual underlying entities are the exact same types. If this is wrong and there are also many `User` types then this will not work.

Comment: The _context is initialize with AEntities / BEntities?

Comment: @DanaEzer - `AEntities` and `BEntities` both derive from `DbContext`. As long as `User` is 1 type and not a derived `AUser` and `BUser` the above code works and is a good abstraction. You can use a DI framework to inject the correct `AEntities` or `BEntities` or use a factory pattern.